# Nested Bluetooth callback in Matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, user-interface, bluetooth, callback, handles

I know the Matlab GUI callbacks have been discussed here hundreds of times, but I think I ran into a special problem.

I know how to share data between the different GUI callbacks (I use the handles-structure as described in the [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html)). I created my GUI with GUIDE.

There is one pushbutton that creates a bluetooth-handle in its callback function, which works just fine. Once the Bluetooth connection is established and a certain amount of bytes is received, a bluetooth-callback function is triggered (set by `bluetoothhandle.BytesAvailavailableFcn = @rdatac_Callback`).

The header of my Bluetooth callback-function looks like this:

```
function rdatac_Callback(hObject, eventdata)
```

The `hObject` contains the bluetooth-handle, `eventdata` the event which triggered the callback (in this case it's called "BytesAvailable").

This function is in the same file as all other GUI callbacks. The problem is that I cannot access the handles structure of the GUI within the bluetooth-callback. I tried adding "handles" as a third input parameter, but then it's empty. I also tried generating my own handles structure by

```
h = guidata(findobj('Name','BCI'));
```

where BCI is the name of the GUI window. This works perfectly in any GUI-callback function, but inside the Bluetooth callback it cannot find the other elements, so the Bluetooth callback has its very own "scope".

So my question is: How can I share all the GUI handles with my Bluetooth callback function? My workaround was using the global workspace, but I would like to use the handles structure if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your bluetooth callback with the signature function `rdatac_Callback(hGuiObject, hBtObject, eventdata)`. Now when creating the bluetooth object in your GUI-Callback you have the handle to your GUI-Object. This should be passed to your rdatac_Callback. You can achive this using the function handle `@(hBtObject,eventdata)rdatac_Callback(hGuiObject, hBtObject, eventdata)`. The function `rdatac_Callback` is always called with the three parameters you need, but only two have to be passed to the anonymous function. `hGuiObject` is taken from the workspace where you created the anonymous function.

Comment: One more thing though: I tried to modify the field `handles.data`  in my Bluetooth callback and save it with `guidata(handles.figure1,handles)` just like I did in the GUI-callbacks (only that I used `handles.figure1` here instead of `hObject`, since there is no `hObject` in the Bluetooth callback), but the data is never stored. Everytime the Bluetooth-callback is triggered `handles.data` is empty. I used `handles.data = [];` in the GUI Opening Fcn to declare this new field in the `handles` structure.